# Is MLMultiArray a flatten array of the model output matrix?

Tags: arrays, swift, machine-learning, coreml

New to CoreML, trying to understand some basic concepts.

I'm working on a model with an output of:

```
float32 [1,896,16]
```

When using the model, and getting the output as `MLMultiArray` I get the following:

```
let output = prediction.regressors // MLMultiArray
print(output.debugDescription) // Float32 1 x 896 x 16 array
print(output.count) // 14336, which is 896x16
```

And I can access each of the elements simply using `output[0]..output[1]..`

Is it true for any data type that'll be stored in the `MLMultiArray`? Is it a "convenient" that Swift supplies us?

If flatten array is the case, will it be ordered at the same order of the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `MLMultiArray` a flatten array of the model output matrix?
[No it's not it's a multidimensional array of the given dimensions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmultiarray/2879232-init)

You can convert it to array like below and it should be the same order of the matrix.

```
let length = output.count
    let doublePtr =  output.dataPointer.bindMemory(to: Double.self, capacity: length)
    let doubleBuffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: doublePtr, count: length)
    let outputArray = Array(doubleBuffer)
```

For Data types apple documentations shows 3 types only: [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmultiarraydatatype)

> **case int32**
>
> Represents the integer type for multidimensional arrays and is
> commonly used for text encoding.
>
> **case float32**
>
> Represents the float type in multidimensional arrays.
>
> **case double**
>
> Represents the double type for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Hey Mohmmad, Thank you for replying! So printing all the values of my `MLMultiArray` as [0]..[1].. and printing each of the elements from your array, will yield a different order? Also, using your code I get crash: `Thread 21: Fatal error: UnsafeMutablePointer.initialize overlapping range`

Comment: @RoiMulia No different order they should be the same, I tested it on playground it works there idk tbh

Comment: Found the issue, we are casting it as Double, but it's Float32. Using Float32 solves the issue

Comment: Mohmmad, do you have experience with CoreML/Machine Learning? None of my team has a deep experience (still learning), but we need some core help lol. Are you available for a paid consultant?

Comment: @RoiMulia I am not actually really experienced one and not currently available unfortunately .. but imo a +3y exp engineers shouldn't have hard time with this and depends on what you guys trying to do with them

Comment: It's more of an issue of understanding the model output (lack of docs) ah, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @RoiMulia sorry I couldn't be more helpful good luck with your team.